# How do I remove empty HREF attributes from Raphael object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, raphael

I would like to unset (remove) href attribute of the Text object.
How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
var paper = Raphael( 0, 0, 100, 100 );
var rect = paper.rect( 0, 0, 100, 100 );

// just set it to nothing
rect.attr({ href: "" });
```